# How to read attached files with roo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to read attached excel files with `roo gem`

My view is

```
<%= form_for @hotel, :url => { :action => "create_by_excel_sheet" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :excel_sheet %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

I tried

```
def create_by_excel_sheet
    xlsxFile = params[:hotel][:excel_sheet]
    prefix_tmp_path = xlsxFile.path
    filename = xlsxFile.original_filename
    fullname = File.join(prefix_tmp_path,filename) 

    s = Roo::Excelx.new(fullname)

    for i in 1..14
      puts s.cell(i,3) 
    end
end
```

But I receive an error `*** IOError Exception: file /tmp/RackMultipart20130921-4175-165dgyw/hotel_information.xlsx does not exist` and edit the code and tried

```
   Roo::Excelx.new(xlsxFile.path)
```

get the error

```
TypeError Exception: /tmp/RackMultipart20130921-4175-165dgyw is not an Excel-xlsx file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution from here http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

Answer (score 3):

Since you know it's an xslx file, you can add this option to ignore the file warning and the exception:

```
Roo::Excelx.new(xlsxFile.path, file_warning: :ignore))
```